# Multiple API calls with Async & Request Package (NodeJS / Express)

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, request

I am trying to implement async and request into an asynchronous API request action within one of my routers.  The end point is just a query string and I'm trying to return an an array or object with the result of all of the calls.  So far there are just two:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel([
        function(next) {
            request(queryString + 'end point string', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var unsPAM = JSON.parse(body);
                };
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        function(next) {
            request(queryString + 'end point string', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var unsAll = JSON.parse(body);
                };
                console.log(error);
            });
        }], 
        function(err, results) {
            res.render("api-results", [results]);
        });
    });
```

This is the just of what I'm trying to do.  If I console.log the result of each variable after the request it works properly, but nothing is being returned and my ejs template is not being served.

I have also tried using something like the below in various formats (array/object form) but I cannot seem to get it working:

```
res.render("api-results", { unsPAM: unsPAM, unsAll: unsAll });
```

I think its because the result of the request's aren't making it to the async array somehow.  Any advice/best practice solutions/change of ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of the functions, you need to invoke the `next()` callback with `null` and the value you want to pass on, or an `error` object if unsuccessful. Without that, `async.parallel()` has no indication that the API calls ever completed.

To reduce the amount of repeated code, you can create a closure with the URL for each API endpoint:

```
function apiCall(url) {
    return function(callback) {
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                return callback(error);
            }

            try {
                return callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
            } catch (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }
        });
    };
}       

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel([
        apiCall(queryString + 'end point string'),
        apiCall(queryString + 'end point string')
    ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.render("api-results", results);
    });
});
```

That will call `res.render()` with `results` as `[unsPAM, unsAll]`. If you would rather `results` be an object with the keys `unsPAM` and `unsAll`, call `async.parallel()` with an object instead of an array as the first parameter:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel({
        unsPAM: apiCall(queryString + 'end point string'),
        unsAll: apiCall(queryString + 'end point string')
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.render("api-results", results);
    });
});
```